# list all tables that don't exist but are used in a view sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I can't seem to get all the table names that a view is trying to use.

Currently, I am using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE` to find which tables are used. But, it only finds tables that currently exist. I want to find out if that view is trying to use tables that don't exist.

`View_Column_Usage` will only find columns that are used in the view. You can check to see if those columns are in any of the current tables columns to find which columns aren't used, but you can't find which tables aren't used.

Does anyone know a table I can use to find which tables are used in a view, but do not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script I found here seems to work to find the views that are broken.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic785213-146-1.aspx#bm785697

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such a thing that stores the information of the not existed objects, simply because they don't exists! I believe that my recommendation is not the exact solution but I think it will help you through the way:

```
Select  *
    From    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
    Left    Outer   Join
        sys.objects
    On  objects.type        =   'U'
    And views.view_definition   Like    '%' +   objects.name    +   '%'
    Where   objects.name        Is  Null
```

Cheers